# invalid operands of types 'double' and 'int' to binary 'operator%'

Tags: c++, arduino

There !

In one of the my project i am trying to print Float value on seven segment display using Arduino Mega2560 with given codes, But i am getting correct data with decimal values but now when i am trying to print float values unfortunately getting the error as mentioned on title.

Float value's code which i am trying to compile

```
switch (current_digit)
{
case 1:
 disp(fmodf (adc_value, 10000000));   //8   
 digitalWrite(digit_7, HIGH);  
 break;
 
case 2:
 disp(fmodf (adc_value, 1000000)% 10);   //7
 digitalWrite(digit_6, HIGH);  
 break;
 
case 3:
 disp(fmodf (adc_value, 100000)% 10);   //6
 digitalWrite(digit_5, HIGH);  
 break;
 
case 4:
 disp(fmodf (adc_value, 10000)% 10);   //5
 digitalWrite(digit_4, HIGH);  
 break;
  
case 5:
  disp(fmodf (adc_value, 1000)% 10); //4  
  digitalWrite(digit_3, HIGH); 
   digitalWrite(SegGDP,LOW); 
  break;

case 6:
  disp( fmodf (adc_value, 100) % 10);  //3 
  digitalWrite(digit_2, HIGH);        
  break;

case 7:
  disp( fmodf (adc_value, 10) % 10);   //2
  digitalWrite(digit_1, HIGH);   
  break;

case 8:
  disp(fmodf (adc_value, 10));   //1
  digitalWrite(digit_0, HIGH);  
}
```

References :

1. [Float value references](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fmod.htm)
2. [Invalid operands of type 'double' and 'int' to binary 'operator%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038902/invalid-operands-of-type-double-and-int-to-binary-operator)

Comment: `fmodf` returns a `float` and you try to do `% 10` on that float. I don't see enough code in your question to write an answer, but perhaps you want `static_cast<int>(fmodf(...)) % 10`? I get the feeling that all this could be greatly simplified though. Too bad you didn't supply a [mre].

Comment: why not just sprintf and convert the chars to the numbers? Much to much code for an embedded system... for my point of view. ok sprintf is much more :-)

Answer (score 1):

`fmodf` returns a float. So

```
fmodf(adc_value, 1000000)% 10
```

will still attempt `float % int`.

However, that code does probably not what you want it to do. The equivalent of

```
(adc_value / 1000000) % 10
```

should be

```
fmodf(adc_value / 1000000.f, 10.f)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Errors are removed

Answer (score 1):

```
case 1:
 disp(fmodf (adc_value, 10000000));   //8
```

You want `floor(adc_value / 10000000)` instead, which would be the float equivalent of the integer division `adc_value / 10000000`.

```
case 2:
 disp(fmodf (adc_value, 1000000)% 10);   //7
```

There is no `%` between a floating point value and an integer, so here is where you want `fmodf` as in `fmodf ( floor(adc_value / 1000000), 10)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Error are removed !